# Precise needs a tag synonym

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I can't synonym [precise](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/precise) to [12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/12.04), the popup says a moderator is needed to make the synonym.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This has been completed, Bruno did it a few hours ago.](https://askubuntu.com/tags/12.04/synonyms)

Comment: I think the real question is why cant @JorgeCastro suggest one in the first place :S

Comment: @BrunoPereira He ran out of synonym votes?